# UPDATE array of row type in a plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql

I have tables representing some geometry as regions (connected areas) grouped into places.  I have a function which is supposed to add a region to a place.  I get the following error which I don't understand.

```
select * from addregion2place(1,1) ;
ERROR:  column "rgnz" does not exist
LINE 1: update only place set rgnz = rgnz || region, 
                                     ^
QUERY:  update only place set rgnz = rgnz || region, 
                                     bx = containingBox( region.bx, bx )
            from region
            where place_id = intoPlace_id and reg_id = region_id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "addregion2place" line 4 at SQL statement
```

I am trying to add the region to the end of the array of regions.  Can someone tell me why `rgnz` is unknown on the right of the `=` but not on the left? More importantly, how to fix?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addRegion2Place( reg_id integer ,  intoPlace_id integer ) returns VOID AS $ar2p$
       DECLARE
       BEGIN
        update only place set rgnz = rgnz || region, 
                                     bx = containingBox( region.bx, bx )
            from region
            where place_id = intoPlace_id and reg_id = region_id;

       END;
$ar2p$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- a closed path
create table if not exists region (
       place_id integer,
       pts polygon,
       bx box CHECK (box(pts) ~= bx), 
       region_id integer DEFAULT nextval('region_region_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL
);

-- place: a collection of regions
create table if not exists place (
       place_id integer DEFAULT nextval('place_place_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
       bx box DEFAULT (NULL),
       rgnz region[]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some column names were ambiguous. Add table-qualification to columns to disambiguate.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addRegion2Place(reg_id integer, intoplace_id integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$ar2p$
BEGIN
   UPDATE ONLY place p
   SET    rgnz = p.rgnz || r
        , bx = containingBox(r.bx, b.bx)  -- guessing; your code was ambiguous
   FROM   region r
   WHERE  p.place_id = intoplace_id       -- more guessing
   AND    r.region_id = reg_id;    
END
$ar2p$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In particular `place_id` and `bx` were ambiguous. Notably, `rgnz` seems ok as is - unless you are not showing original definitions. You didn't disclose your version of Postgres. Older version had different levels of tolerance for these ambiguities (which ultimately always lead to an exception).

Also make sure that `region.region_id` and `place.place_id` are unique, or your `UPDATE` goes haywire. I don't see a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint in your table definition.